# Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed

Tags: spring-mvc

**OrderController**

```
@Controller
    public class OrderController {

        @Autowired
        private OrderService orderService;

        @RequestMapping("/order/P1234/2")
        public String getRequestProcessed() {
            orderService.processOrder("P1234", 3);
            return "redirect:/products";
        }
    }
```

**ProductController**

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping("/products")
    public String getAllProducts(Model model) {
        System.out.println(productService.getAllProducts());
        model.addAttribute("products", productService.getAllProducts());
        return "products";
    }
```

**OrderServiceImpl**

```
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepositiry productRepositiry;

    @Override
    public void processOrder(String productId, long count) {
        Product product = productRepositiry.getProductById(productId);
        if (count > product.getUnitsInStock())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out Of Order " + productId);
        else
            product.setUnitsInStock(product.getUnitsInStock() - count);
    }
```

**Stack Trace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productService': No qualifying bean of type [com.webstore.service.ProductService] found for dependency [com.webstore.service.ProductService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.webstore.service.ProductService] found for dependency [com.webstore.service.ProductService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.webstore.service.ProductService] found for dependency [com.webstore.service.ProductService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 31 more
```

I am new to spring so I'm not sure what went wrong if you need more information please ask and please help me to resolve this when I try to fetch data directly from `reopositiry` it's working but when I'm trying to fetch from `@repositiry`->`@service` to all `@controllers` I am getting error,

**Edit**

**Product Service**

```
@Service
public interface ProductService {

    List<Product> getAllProducts();

    Product getProductById(String productId);

}
```

help me to solve this

Thanks

Comment: where is `com.webstore.service.ProductService`?

Comment: @Arpit I have added the `productService interface`

Answer (score 1):

Try annotate your **Implementations** like `OrderServiceImpl` with `@Component` from package `org.springframework.stereotype.Component`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bean declared in the application context that is suited to be used to autowire the `productService` field marked with `@Autowire`

You need to declare a bean that implements `com.webstore.service.ProductService` like you did with `OrderServiceImpl` for `com.webstore.service.OrderService`

Comment: actually  `productService` is annotated with `@service` annotation

Answer (score 0):

you are missing ProductService class

```
package com.packt.webstore.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.packt.webstore.domain.Product;

public interface ProductService {
    public List<Product> getAllProducts();

    public List<Product> getProductsByCategory(String category);

    Set<Product> getProductsByFilter(Map<String, List<String>> filterParams);

    Product getProductById(String productID);

    Set<Product> getFilteredProducts(Map<String, List<String>> filterParams, String manufacturer);

    void    addProduct(Product  product);



}
```

and ProductServiceImpl

```
package com.packt.webstore.service.impl;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.packt.webstore.domain.Product;
import com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository;
import com.packt.webstore.service.ProductService;

@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

@Autowired
ProductRepository productRepository;
public List<Product> getAllProducts(){
    List<Product> list = productRepository.getAllProducts();
    return list;
}

public List<Product> getProductsByCategory(String category){
    return productRepository.getProductsByCategory(category);
}

public Set<Product> getProductsByFilter(Map<String, List<String>> filterParams){
    return productRepository.getProductsByFilter(filterParams);
}

public Product getProductById(String productID){
    return productRepository.getProductById(productID);
}

public Set<Product> getFilteredProducts(Map<String, List<String>> filterParams, String manufacturer){
    return productRepository.getFilteredProducts(filterParams, manufacturer);
}

public void addProduct(Product product){
    productRepository.addProduct(product);
}
}
```

Comment: you are right but using annotations with `interface` is good practice and thanks for the code :)

Comment: But I want to go with hard way

Comment: what exactly you want to do ? use xml for declaring beans

Comment: this is not the answer for execption

Comment: lol figure it out your self and post the answer here when you find it